# Why won't this <ul> center perfectly horizontally?

Tags: html, css, centering

Edit2: Sorry, I messed up this whole question. I am centering an ul, and it'll be slightly off to the right. If I do the same exact thing using divs, it'll center correctly.

Here I use div: http://cssdeck.com/labs/rt6p03qe
Here I use ul: http://cssdeck.com/labs/g4iyhnqb

As you can see, they are slightly offset, even though the code is the same for both.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/rt6p03qe and there are **four** boxes.

Comment: They are not slightly off to the right, they are all the way to the left. I tried it in IE, Firefox and Chrome. There is nothing in the code that would center the boxes.

Comment: Centering is pretty well covered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UL's have built in padding. Set your UL's to padding: 0 and it'll not be offset.